# Is it safe to replace GCC's system-level C++ runtime with a version from newer GCC?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Linux C++ programs build with GCC link against `libgcc_s.so.1` and `libstdc++.so.6` libraries, each of which contains multiple ABIs: newer versions contain ABIs from previous version plus new ones. [GCC ABI policy document](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) says programs build against older runtime should be able to be run with the new runtime. So, theoretically, older binaries should be runnable on new systems.

If I have a system with an older runtime and don't want to go through the trouble of upgrading GCC on this system, can I manually replace the above mentioned libraries with new ones? In theory all old executables that link against it should work (including GCC itself), but it feels like a kludge.

*Is it safe to do so?*

Comment: Not a programming question, voting to move to superuser.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, I disagree. This requires specific knowledge about the way GCC C++ ABI is implemented as well as practical experience with mixing those libs.

Comment: While it's useful for a programmer to know ABI details, this is fundamentally a system administration question.  Programmers often have to know about system administration, but there isn't any first party code involved in this question.

Comment: @Ben: No sysadmin could provide a meaningful answer to this question without significant knowledge of GCC, C++, and ABIs that would _never_ come with normal sysadmin duties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Maybe*, but I don't recommend it, at least not without extensive testing that would almost certainly eat up any gain. Here's why:

- "ABI compatible" is not necessarily "bug compatible". Even if ABI compatibility is maintained, your apps might still break in surprising ways if they somehow depended on behavior that was incorrect in a previous version of the library.
- There might be *new* bugs that end up breaking your apps, again without being ABI-incompatible.
- If you don't compile the new libraries *exactly right*, they might *not* be ABI compatible.
- Are you sure the original libraries were compiled from pristine GNU sources? Maybe there were patches you don't know about. If you can't be sure of that, you can't be sure of compatibility of your existing system/apps.

What's your goal here? If you just want to be able to compile C++ apps that use newer features, you can install a new version of GCC alongside the original, you just need to make sure all the libraries you might be using are built with the new version, too.

Comment: What I'd like to build with GCC 4.5 and deploy on a system that only has libstdc++ from GCC 4.1 or 4.2. But barring a parallel install of a new GCC version it looks less and less like a good idea.

Comment: @Alex: If it comes down to it, I'd statically link. The binary might be huge (relatively speaking), but for a one-off thing, I wouldn't worry about it, and you'd save all the headache of worrying about library versions. Just drop the static binary on the old system and go.

Comment: @AlexB: Ancient response, but: Try configuring the new GCC with the install directories pointed at your existing system directories. Copy the configure from your distro's build scripts. But then do not use make install. You can do a make install into a temp directory (look at the distro packaging scripts) and from there do a manual install or create your own distro package that excludes all of the new libraries.